# How to permute two strings in c#

Tags: c#

I have two strings which I need to compare and permute. What is the best way of doing this?

Given a string "asdfpoit" what is the best way to rerrange it to match another string "poitasdf"?

I know this can be done using nested for loops... but is there a better/faster way of doing this?

Comment: Use recursion, not nested for loops. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @AntarrByrd I am trying to re-arrange a string to match another string